# Prevent resubmission when using META REFRESH

Tags: php, redirect, refresh

When an user submits a form and everything worked, he will get a success message with a META REFRESH of 3 seconds. Then the page refreshes, but when I click the refresh button or F5, the page asks me if I want to resubmit, meaning that META REFRESH didn't actually redirect and clear everything.

Is there a way to prevent data resubmission when using META REFRESH?

I could've used `header('Location: somewhere.php');`, but I wouldn't be able to show a success message with it.

I am using META REFRESH with PHP headers, like this `header("refresh:3;url=" . $home_action);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `header('location: somewhere.php?message=success')` and on the page `somewhere.php` you can check for existence of the `message` get variable and output a success message if you see one.

This is the way that it usually gets done. Another way is to set a `$_SESSION` variable and check for that on `somewhere.php`. If it exists remember to remove it from the session.

Comment: I tried the first method and it works great. I can't actually believe I didn't think of this earlier - Thank you.